# react-router cannot resolve module history, missing lib folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

I'm creating a new React project and I have a dependency issue between `react-router` and `history` :

```
ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/match.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/Actions' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/match.js 15:15-45

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/useRouterHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/useQueries' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/useRouterHistory.js 6:18-51

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/useQueries' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js 6:18-51

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/useRouterHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/useBasename' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/useRouterHistory.js 10:19-53

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/useBasename' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js 10:19-53

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/browserHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/browserHistory.js 5:28-71

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/hashHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/createHashHistory' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/hashHistory.js 5:25-65

ERROR in ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory' in /app/node_modules/react-router/lib
@ ./~/react-router/lib/createMemoryHistory.js 14:27-69
```

I'm using `react-router` last release `3.0.0` which has `history` `3.0.0` as a dependency in its `package.json`.
I'm using `npm` version `3.10.8` and even if `history` module is installed by `react-router` dependency, I added it in my `package.json` too, as stated in `react-router` docs.

Thing is `react-router` is searching its requires in `history/lib/` while `history` module has its files in `history/` (no `lib` folder).

Since it doesn't depend on my configuration/installation but on third parties modules, I don't see what to do and I'm surprised to not find any issue regarding this.

Comment: You can try to delete the node_modules folder and then run npm install.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri already tried all the basics stuff like cleaning, reinstalling, etc. No improvement, the history module doesn't have a lib folder whatever i have tried

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is actually to follow `react-router` installation instructions, adding `history` module in our own `package.json`.

Installing the last version of `history` on your own instead of the one required by `react-router` is creating this conflict.

With `react-router` >= 3.0, `history` is a dependency with a fixed version requirement, installed along with `react-router` itself :

```
└─┬ react-router@3.0.0
  └── history@3.2.1
```

no need to install it manually in your `package.json`, it will create conflicts if you don't specify the right required version.

Thanks to @ShubhamKhatri for having pointing me in this direction.

Comment: Yes, You right. It has happened to me when I upgrade history to latest version. I have to downgrade it to be history@3.2.1 to fix it. Seem "lib" directory has been removed after version 3.2.1

Answer (score 7):

If you are using  npm version greater than 3.0.0 .

Note that you need to also install the `history` package since it is a peer dependency of `React Router` and won't automatically be installed for you in npm version freater than 3.0.0.

Run `npm install history` and you should be good.

Comment: I already know that, and I added `history` in my package.json. In any case, the module is present, that's not the issue here, the problem is that `react-router` is referencing a wrong path while calling `history` libraries

Comment: The answer was to actually do the exact opposite, but thanks because of you I investigated furthermore with modules version and requirements and find the solution

Answer (score 3):

The path needs to be updated it is no longer

> history/lib/createHashHistory

It's just

> history/createHashHistory

[React Training Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history)

Also probably import HashRouter from react-route-dom. HashRouter replaces Router and no need to pass history as a prop anymore.